# Xamarin Android: Dynamic update UI based on Viewmodel

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

In my android project, the webview url is dynamic. I am using mvvmcros binding on view side but its not being dynamic. If the url content on view model is changing its not being updated on view. Can anyone help me out?

**View**

```
public string WebContentUrll { get; set; }    
protected override void OnCreate(Android.OS.Bundle bundle)    
{        
  var bindingSet = this.CreateBindingSet<view, ViewModel>(); 
  bindingSet.Bind(this).For(v => v.WebContentUrll).To(vm => vm.WebContentUrl).TwoWay();    
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
   private string webContentUrl;      
    public string WebContentUrl      
    {       
     get       
     {        
       return webContentUrl;       
     }       
     set       
     {        
      webContentUrl = value;        
      RaisePropertyChanged(() => webContentUrl);       
     }      
    }
  public void Init()
  {
     webContentUrl = "https://.."'
  }
```

The value of web content url in the view model changes after the page is loaded but the android view is not able to get the new updated url.

Can anyone please advise. Thank you.

**Update**

The web view is opened on a button click and the url is updated after the page loads and before the button is clicked

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do here. Are you using a WebView control in the View? Is the ViewModel responsible for changing the URL? The way you have it now, it simply changes the property on the View... it doesn't load a new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you description in the opening post. In your Activity you have defined a property `WebContentUrll`. You want to bind this and update something when it is changed.

The definition of `WebContentUrll` is:

```cs
public string WebContentUrll { get; set; }
```

This is not wrong and you should see the value reflected in `WebContentUrll` when it changes from the ViewModel through your binding. However, there is no code updating any visual states, views or anything based on that property.

If you have a WebView you want to change content for, you could modify your property to something like:

```cs
private string _webContentUrll;
public string WebContentUrll
{
    get => _webContentUrll;
    set 
    {
        _webContentUrll = value;
        _webView.LoadUrl(_webContentUrll);
    }
 }
```

Given that `_webView` is your instance of a `WebView`.